# Написать функцию которая возвращает отформатированную дату

Tags: javascript

Каждый месяц должен отображаться как 3 буквы (например, Feb, Apr либо Dec)

```
 myDate(new Date('2020-08-10T01:10:00')) // возвращает 'It is 10 of Aug, 2020'
```

Я нашла функцию которая возвращает сегодняшнюю дату но не знаю как переделать по нужному мне шаблону

```
function join(t, a, s) {
  function format(m) {
    let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', m);
    return f.format(t);
  }
  return a.map(format).join(s);
}
let a = [{ day: 'numeric' }, { month: 'short' }, { year: 'numeric' }];
let s = join(new Date, a, ' ');
console.log(s);
```

Comment: А вот если не "находить" функцию, а делать самостоятельно, то и такая простая задача не вызовет затруднений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function join(t, a, s) {
            function format(m) {
                let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', m);
                return f.format(t);
            }
            let [day, month, year] = a.map(format);
            return `It is ${day} of ${month}, ${year}`;
        }
        let a = [{
            day: 'numeric'
        }, {
            month: 'short'
        }, {
            year: 'numeric'
        }];
        let s = join(new Date('2020-08-10T01:10:00'), a);
        console.log(s);
```

Comment: Можете подробней объяснить принцип работы?